# item expand with v-slot:expanded-row and v-slot:item

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

can anyone tell me how to expand in vuetify 3 data table please using both the item and expanded-row slots together? Just cant figure out why the expand doesn't show if I add the item slot and cant find anything that explains how to do this. Works if i just have the expanded- row slot but then i cant edit the items...thanks

```
          <template v-slot:expanded-row="{ columns, item }" >
            <tr>
                <td :colspan="columns.length">
                    More info about {{ item.name }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            </template>

            <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                <td><v-chip :color="getColor(item.calories)">{{ item.calories }}</v-chip></td>
                <td>{{ item.fat }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.carbs }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.protein }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.iron }}</td> 
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When overriding the default item row, you also have to override the button to expand rows.

The `item` slot has two slot props, `isExpanded` and `toggleExpand`, both are functions that take the `internalItem`, which is also passed to the slot. With this, you can build your own expand button:

```html
<template #item="{item, columns, internalItem, isExpanded, toggleExpand}">
  <tr>
    <td v-for="column in columns">
      <v-btn
        v-if="column.key === 'data-table-expand'"
        :icon="isExpanded(internalItem) ? 'mdi-chevron-up' : 'mdi-chevron-down'"
        variant="plain"
        @click="toggleExpand(internalItem)"
      />
      <span v-else>{{item[column.key]}}</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)